# Dynamic form fields on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, dynamic

I'm starting to programming on Ruby on Rails and I need some help.

I have some models:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :parsets
  has_many :parameters, -> { select('parameters.*, parsets.*') }, through: :parsets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parameters
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :devices, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parameters
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Parameter < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parsets
  has_many :devices, -> { select('devices.*, parsets.*') }, through: :parsets
end

class Parset < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :parameter
end
```

Categories may contain some parameters ('parameters' table have columns 'name' and 'value_type'). Each device have a parset ('parsets' table have columns 'device_id', 'parameter_id' and 'value' for parameter value). // Parset - is "parameters set".

I want to dynamically create form_fields for device parameters based on chosen categories.

Now I have a piece of code that doesn't work (it is only for test and the logic will be placed in the controller later):

```
<%= form_for @device do |f| %>
  # ... some form fields here ...

  <% @allparams = [] %>

  <% @device.categories.each do |cat| %>
    <% cat.parameters.each do |par| %>
      <% @allparams.push par %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% @allparams.uniq.each do |par| %>
    <%= f.send(par.value_type.to_sym, par.name) %><br />
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Please help me to realise dynamically generated form fields.

Comment: "Now I have a piece of code that doesn't work" seems a bit ambiguous what does "doesn't  work" mean in this case? Error, nothing rendered, the wold comes to a screeching halt?

Comment: In this case I have an error with "par.name":
undefined method `par2' for #<Device:0x007f03624d0578>. Where 'par2' is the parameter name. But in the parameters table, not in devices table.

Comment: If I use 'par.name' without 'f.send', I get all parameters names correctly. But I want to use it for generating form fields.

Comment: Since the pars are not attributes of the `Device` model itself you will need to use a nested attributes to handle these fields. This method is called `#fields_for` and works very similar to `form_for` but will nested the parameters under the original model like `{device: { parset_attributes: [{parameter_id: 1, value: value}, {parameter_id: 2, value: value}]}}` have a look [`ActionView::Helpers#fields_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't understand how can I generate only fields for parameters based on chosen categories for device. Nothing rendered in this case:   <%= f.fields_for :parameters || @device.parameters.new do |par| %>
    <%= par.object.name %>: <%= par.text_field :value, class: 'form-control' %><br>
    <%= par.text_field :value_type, class: 'form-control' %><br>
  <% end %>

Comment: <%= device.fields_for :parsets do |parset| %> <% @allparams.uniq.each do |param| %> <%= parset.label param.name %> <%= parset.text_field :value, class: 'form-control' %> <% end %> <% end %> Now I have <label for="device_parsets_attributes_0_par1">Par1</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="12345" name="device[parsets_attributes][0][value]" id="device_parsets_attributes_0_value">
<label for="device_parsets_attributes_0_par2">Par2</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="12345" name="device[parsets_attributes][0][value]" id="device_parsets_attributes_0_value">